# I want to modify linux kernel and make iso image of kernel

Tags: virtualization

I'm studying about virtualization.
I want to modify a kernel and make a iso image of Ubuntu.
Then, I want to load that iso file to qemu.
Is it possible and how to do it?

Comment: I assume this is going to be off topic; in this case using Ubuntu is a side effect; you can replace "ubuntu" with any other operating system based on Linux and the answer will be the same. You probably need to ask this somewhere dedicated to kernel development. This will be a better place: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel

Answer (score 0):

Well, not to be too self-serving, but you're going to be looking for a UNIX based utility that can do cloning and bare metal recovery.  The software company I work for does just that and you could use the free trial to do your clone.

http://www.storix.com/free-trial

It will package everything up nicely and allow you to go from physical to virtual.  Just make a Full System Backup of your Ubuntu system, make a recovery disk, attach the recovery disk to your VM, and boot.

-Rick